# What is "getUpsertedId" in WriteResult and can I avoid the creation of it?

Tags: mongodb

When I execute

```
db.Collection.remove( { _id: ObjectId('xxxxx') }, { justOne: true } )
```

the MongoDB returns the WriteResult with the number of documents updated. In this document, there is another document "getUpsertedId" with contains quite a lot of Javascript code.

What is the reason for this and is it possible to avoid the MongoDB to return this (unnecessary) data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute any of the Operations on a collection such as `insert, update, remove or save` then `WriteResult` which is a wrapper contains the result of the query executed will be returned. Please see [WriteResult](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/WriteResult/) and [WriteResult api](http://api.mongodb.com/java/2.6.5/com/mongodb/WriteResult.html).

It is not possible to avoid the MongoDB to return the WriteResult while executing `insert, update, remove or save` queries.

Hope it Helps!